# is there an API for the displaying of an activity indicator followed by a checkmark, as in Apple's wallpaper loading screen?

Tags: iphone, activity-indicator

http://www.angrypuppetsoftware.com/imagehost/photo3.png

http://www.angrypuppetsoftware.com/imagehost/photo2.png

When you set a wallpaper on the iPhone, it shows some sort of activity indicator, followed by a checkmark (see screenshots above). Is there any way to integrate this into an application programmatically?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing built in to the SDK. You can roll your own UIview or this should cover what you are trying to do quite nicely: http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Comment: No problem. I was very happy when I found out about this last week - glad it will do the trick for you too.